# Pyside UI pops up and then disappears when run from cmd before it can be used?

Tags: python, user-interface, cmd, pyside

I am fairly new to python and have made a simple UI using pyside. When run from inside the  anaconda IDE the UI works fine, but when I run it using anaconda from the command line \python.exe 'runquacker.py' the UI flashes up and disappears immediately. 
The initial script is:

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import sys
import quacker

class MainDialog(QDialog, quacker.Ui_Dialog):    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = MainDialog()
form.show()
```

The rest of the UI is in quacker.py which collects a bunch of variables from the user, before executing a further analysis.py program using a subprocesscall. The variables are all passed in this way because thats the only way I could get pyside to work with my script!
e.g. For two variables 'plots' and 'block':

```
subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'd:\\py\\anaconda\\analysis.py', str(plots), str(block)], shell=True)
```

Ive tried putting a raw_input('Blah..') in a few places but it just causes the program to hang or nothing at all.

Using \python.exe -i runquacker.py also causes the program to hang.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this line at the end of your script: `app.exec_()`
That's because you need to actually *execute* your Qt application if you whant to *see* something.
I'm not pretty sure why it works in Anaconda but if you are using some IDE like Spyder I think it works because Spyder is already running in Qt (so it called `QApplication.exec_` before).